# How to select based on time elapsed, with a time field

Tags: mysql, sql, time

I have this data

```
Name  | ValidSince |RecordNumber
Jean  | 10-10-2013 | J112
Mark  | 10-20-2013 | K121
Shane | 10-22-2013 | L109
Bettie| 10-14-2013 | J349
```

I am trying to make a query that works something like this :

```
SELECT * from table where ValidSince > (NOW - 1 WEEK);
```

(where NOW is today (22-10-2013) )

So that the output is Mark and Shane because of their dates

Please advice

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * from table where ValidSince > getdate()-7
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query could be

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable
WHERE ValidSince > DATE_SUB(NOW, INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```